# Basic Corporate Portrait Shooting

Tags: portrait

My company is implementing employee badges. I'd like to purchase some equipment for a basic portrait format and then create a procedure for producing the portraits.

Could anyone describe the basic tools required for portrait shooting; is there a recommended a kit? Is there any advice about how to set up the shooting area?

I am starting with a DSLR that has an 18-55mm lens.